# perl libXML crash when validating against XSD

Tags: linux, perl, debian, libxml2, xml-libxml

I'm migrating an app to the latest Debian and I get a strange server error when validating XML against a XSD

```
use strict;
use feature qw( :5.10.0 );

use XML::LibXML;

my $xsd = q{
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="shiporder">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="shipto">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
};

my $soap=q{
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <shiporder
        orderid="889923"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd">
      <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
      <shipto>
        <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
      </shipto>
    </shiporder>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
};

my $xmlparser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $xmlparser->parse_string($soap);
my $nodelist = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 'Body');

say $nodelist->[0]->toString();

XML::LibXML::Schema->new(string => $xsd)->validate($nodelist->[0]);
```

which causes

> *** glibc detected**  perl: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001cca220 **
>   ======= Backtrace: ========= /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76d76)[0x7fa0edd5fd76]
>   /usr/lib/perl5/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so(PmmREFCNT_dec+0xa3)[0x7fa0ed27c543]
>   /usr/lib/perl5/auto/XML/LibXML/LibXML.so(XS_XML_*LibXML*_Node_DESTROY+0xeb)[0x7fa0ed260a4b]
>   /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14(Perl_pp_entersub+0x58c)[0x7fa0ee7ce70c]
>   /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14(Perl_runops_standard+0x16)[0x7fa0ee7c5ce6]
>   /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14(Perl_call_sv+0x45b)[0x7fa0ee7619db]
>   /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14(Perl_sv_clear+0x559)[0x7fa0ee7d4bd9]
>   /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14(Perl_sv_free2+0x52)[0x7fa0ee7d5292]
>   /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14(Perl_leave_scope+0x122f)[0x7fa0ee7fccef]
>   /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14(Perl_pp_leave+0xf2)[0x7fa0ee7cb112]
>   /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14(Perl_runops_standard+0x16)[0x7fa0ee7c5ce6]
>   /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14(perl_run+0x3a5)[0x7fa0ee767815]
>   perl(main+0x149)[0x400f89]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7fa0edd07ead]
>   perl[0x400fc1]
>   ======= Memory map: ======== 00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 137813                             /usr/bin/perl
>
> and so on

I think it is failing when trying to free the memory allocated. I've tried cloning the objects but nothing seems to stop it. This is failing on a clean install of wheezy and jessie

Comment: You should [report this as a bug](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML). I know the author, Shlomi will look into it. Alternatively, you can use [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig).

Comment: I reported it https://bitbucket.org/shlomif/perl-xml-libxml/issue/3/memory-crash-when-validating-xml-against . thanks for confirming I hadn't missed something obvious

Comment: @DanDascalescu Does XML::Twig support schema validation?

Answer (score 0):

The *validate* method in *XML::LibXML::Schema* only works with whole documents. *libxml2* also provides [*xmlSchemaValidateOneElement*](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlschemas.html#xmlSchemaValidateOneElement) but there are no bindings for this function in *XML::LibXML*.

**EDIT:** This was fixed in *XML::LibXML* 2.0112. Now you can [pass nodes to *validate*](https://metacpan.org/changes/release/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0112).

Answer (score 0):

as @nwellnhof said in a separate answer, validate expects a document as a parameter, rather than a node

So I created a new document from the node and then it validates

```
my $xmlparser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $xmlparser->parse_string($soap);
my ($node) = $doc->findnodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*');

my $newDoc = XML::LibXML::Document->new("1.0");

$newDoc->setDocumentElement($node->cloneNode(1));
say $newDoc;

XML::LibXML::Schema->new(string => $xsd)->validate($newDoc);
```

Comment: If you need to add namespace attributes this is the approach         `my $newDoc = XML::LibXML::Document->new("1.0");
        my $newNode = $nodelist[0]->getChildrenByTagName('*')->shift()->cloneNode(1);

        $newNode->setAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        $newDoc->setDocumentElement($newNode);`